# ICT Tier 2 Move back to UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I have a valid ICT Visa till Aug 2016 and I recently moved back to India in Jan 2016 and my employer has informed UKBA about my movement back to India and end of assignment and also filled returns about my exit from UK, but now we have immediate requirement

Can I travel back to UK on the same visa?
Should my employer inform UKBA again ?

Comment: Your employer has to go through the rigmarole. Don't go back because UKVI will have curtailed your permit.  This is an Expats question, please migrate.

Comment: @GayotFow Have you flagged it for migration?

Comment: @JoErNanO thanks for the reminder, I just did it

Comment: Would you describe what is needed for this 'immediate requirement'? Is it a short term project that they have to have you present for? Or will this require you to go back for an extended unknown period of time?

Comment: Yes ..It is short term for 3 months

Answer (score 1):

With the notification from your employer, the UKVI will have curtailed your permit, and you could not use it to re-enter the UK. Once you left the country and UKVI was so advised, your [Tier 2 Intra-Company Transfer visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/overview) is no longer valid, regardless of the expiration date shown.

In order to return, you and your company would need repeat the visa application, sponsorship, certification, and issuance process.